# Loop through all the Jinja Template Files and Copy to Target Directory

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a collection of .jinja2 templates in the templates directory which I have parameterized in Ansible.

```
└── roles
    ├── copyFiles
    │   ├── tasks
    │   │   └── main.yml
    │   └── templates
    │       ├── file.one.name.xml.jinja2
    │       ├── file.two.name.xml.jinja2
    │       ├── file.three.name.xml.jinja2
    |       ...
```

I would like to copy the files to target directory. However, I don't want to specify each individual Jinja template in a with_items dictionary like below.

```
---
  - name: Copy the Configuration templates
    template:
      src: "templates/{{ item.src }}"
      dest: "target/{{ item.dest }}"
      owner: "{{ user}}"
      group: "{{ group }}"
      mode: 0644
    with_items:
      - { src: 'file.one.name.xml.jinja2', dest: 'file.one.name.xml' }
      - { src: 'file.two.name.xml.jinja2', dest: 'file.two.name.xml' }
      - { src: 'file.three.name.xml.jinja2', dest: 'file.three.name.xml' }
      ...
```

Is there a way to dynamically carry out the template rendering and copying to target for any .jinja2 files in the templates directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way. I used regex to list all the files in the templates directory using its relative path. Then use regex_replace to construct the new name which will be used for the destination file:

```
---
  - name: Copy the Configuration templates
    template:
      src:  "{{ item }}"
      dest: "target/{{ item | basename | regex_replace('\.jinja2','') }}"
      owner: "{{ user}}"
      group: "{{ group }}"
      mode: 0644
    with_fileglob:
       - ../templates/*.jinja2
```

Comment: I got an error with `regex_replace('\.jinja2','')`. Solved it by adding an additional slash: `regex_replace('\\.jinja2','')`